# What effect does diameter and length of a wire have on the force and extension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, length

For example, if wire $A$ has diameter $D$ and length $L$ when a force of $4N$ is applied, it extends to let's say, $0.8mm$.
Another wire $B$ has length and diameter $2L$ and $2D$ respectively. Now, will the extension be greater or lower?

By the way, both wires obey Hooke's law and are identical except for their dimensions (i.e. same material, same young modulus, etc.)

Please help.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it has been specified that Hooke's law is applicable, we use the formula,

$Y=\frac{F}{A}\frac{l}{\Delta l}$ .

Placing the respective values in their positions in the formula and equating $Y$ , we get a value for the extension of the wire $B$.

Please remember that Physics Stack Exchange does not allow exact solutions to homework questions, and any answer which provides such is likely to be flagged and removed.